# elasticsearch on kubernetes giving me resource not found errors when running guide

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm trying to follow this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html and was able to get as far as running `curl -u "elastic:$PASSWORD" -k "https://localhost:9200"` successfully.  However, I tried running it again from step 1 on and am now unable to get past `kubectl get pods --selector='elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name=quickstart'` and I get: `No resources found in default namespace.`

I thought cleaning up all the ECK stuff following this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-uninstalling-eck.html and restarting would fix the issue, but it doesn't seem to.  For example, I have a manifest file that I named `elasticsearch.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: my-elasticsearch
spec:
  version: 7.12.1
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

and for some reason, I'm seeing this when running `kubectl get pods`:

```
my-elasticsearch-depl-6d6f76dd64-4v5q2   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          5m40s
my-elasticsearch-depl-7fcfc47f59-sprsv   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          11h
```

When I try deleting either one of them with `kubectl delete pod my-elasticsearch-depl-6d6f76dd64-4v5q2` , a new one gets automatically generated as well.

I was wondering how to first get rid of these weird zombie pods and then how I might be able to get the basic ECK setup running. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you rename `metadata.name: quickstart` to `my-elasticsearch`, then you'll need to rename it in `kubectl get pods --selector='elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name=quickstart'` as well.
2. Just deleting a pod won't get rid of it while the operator is still running. Have you really run `kubectl delete elastic --all` to remove all resources created by the Elastic operator (and if you have been switching around namespaces, in the right namespace(s))?

Comment: ah, thanks! that makes sense. that takes care of my being able to access it now. I'm now stuck at deleting `quickstart`, which hangs forever, either through deleting it only or through`kubectl delete elastic --all. The newly created `my-elasticsearch` gets deleted fine through that though.

Comment: Not sure how much the operator will fight you on this one. But since you have removed `my-elasticsearch`, why not change back to `quickstart` in the YAML and then clean up with `kubectl delete elastic --all`?